# Differentiate between default image and user image from google/FB response

Tags: php, facebook, google-api, response

Is there a way to differentiate between default image and user image from google/FB response?
what I want is to display it(the image) as a profile pic of that user only if a user has one in Google/FB (not the default pic provided by them like this one)

[image: default response which we get from google when user has not added any image]

thanx in advance any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can be 99.99 percent certain that the image is not user-chosen profile image - but a default, if it's size is less than 10k. I know google default is about 6k, facebooks around same.

Comment: in my case, it's size is 67kb

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook: You can request the user picture using parameter `redirect=false`, then it will return a JSON data structure that contains a property `is_silhouette` - if that is true, then it means the user did not set a profile picture, and the image you got is the default one.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/